# The remainder can be negative?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> What is the remainder of the $13^{16} - 2^{25} 5^{15} \mod{3}$?

I resolved like this:

for $13^{16}\mod{3}\\$:
\begin{align}
13 \equiv 1\mod{3} \to 13^{16} \equiv1 \mod{3}\\
\end{align}

for $2^{25}\mod{3}\\$:
\begin{align}
2^2 \equiv 1 \mod{3}\\
2^{20}\equiv 1 \mod{3}\\
2^{20}*2^5 \equiv 2^5 \mod3\\
2^{25} \equiv 2 \mod3
\end{align}

for $5^{15}\mod{3}\\$:
\begin{align}
5\equiv 2 \mod{3}\\
5^2\equiv4 \mod3\\
5^2\equiv1 \mod3\\
5^{14}*5\equiv 5 \mod3
\end{align}

So, $5^{15}\equiv5 \mod3 * 2^{25}\equiv2 \mod3 \to 2^{25}*5^{15}\equiv10 \mod3$
and
\begin{align}
2^{25}*5^{15} \equiv10 \mod3\\
- 13^{16} \equiv 1 \mod3 \to\\
13^{16}-2^{25}*5^{25} \equiv -9 \mod3
\end{align}

But for Euclidean algorithm the remainder is always positive. What's wrong?

Comment: Nothings wrong.  As $-9\equiv 0\mod 3$ the answer is $0$.

Comment: -9 mod 3 is same as 0 mod 3. Note that the whole computation can be reduced by working in $\Bbb Z/3=\Bbb F_3$, the field with three elements as $13^{16} - 2^{25} 5^{15}=1^{16} - (-1)^{25} (-1)^{15}=1-(-1)(-1)=1-1=0$, and this is still too explicit.

Comment: But you are working too hard.  $13\equiv 1$ and $2\equiv 5\equiv -1$ so $13^{16}-2^{25}5^{15}\equiv 1^{16}-(-1)^{25}(-1)^{15}\equiv 0\mod 3$.

Comment: @fleablood really is most simple! Thanks, I will simplify my resolution in next questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this isn't the Euclidean algorithm.

Secondly, if I understand correctly, you've worked out the remainder to be $1 - 10 \mod 3$. This is correct. The answer is $-9 \mod 3$, or, in a simpler form, $0 \mod 3$ (as $-9 \equiv 0 \mod 3$).